# Process env retuning undefined NUXT 2.12 SPA

Tags: nuxt.js, dotenv

I am using Nuxt v2.12.2 in SPA mode and want to use env variables within the default `head`. I am using `@nuxtjs/dotenv` however when the page is rendered the `baseUrl` is undefined.

**.env**

```
BASE_URL=https://example.com
```

**nuxt.config.js**

```
require('dotenv').config()

export default {
  mode: 'spa',

  generate: {
    fallback: true
  },

  env: {
    baseUrl: process.env.BASE_URL || 'http://localhost:3000'
  },

  head: {
    meta: [
      {
        hid: 'og:image',
        name: 'og:image',
        content: process.env.baseUrl + '/og/facebook.png'
      }
    ],
  },

  modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/dotenv'
  ]

  ...
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```js
...all other content
buildModules: [
    '@nuxtjs/dotenv'
  ]
//buildMdules not modules
```

Also,

```
BASE_URL = https://example.com
```

This might just solve your issue.

Comment: ``process.env.baseUrl`` is still undefined

Comment: @Simon, of course, it is because you have a `BASE_URL` and not a `baseUrl` in your env file.

Comment: Thank you so much! After hours of headache, adding the build module `@nuxtjs/dotenv` solved the issue and all values are propagated to `process.env`

Comment: @barfoos This is a part of our lives.

Answer (score 1):

In order to access env variables within component you need to propagate your process.env.whatever values under an env key in your module.exports so that your components can access them too. In this case, I want NODE_ENV

**nuxt.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  env: {
    NODE_ENV: process.env.NODE_ENV
  },
  ...
}
```

Ref.
https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/5721#issuecomment-582032983